# Unable to post a cross origin request in Django website

Tags: javascript, python, django

Even after installing CORS middle ware and enabling Cross Origin Requests also. I am unable to make a post request by using Javascript.

```
const csrf = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    return {
    'X-CSRFToken' : csrf,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*"
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"};
```

And also in Django app

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'127.0.0.1',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
'x-requested-with',
'content-type',
'accept',
'origin',
'authorization',
'x-csrftoken',
'x-api-key'
)
```

And also after adding CORS Middleware,

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set Access-Control-Request-Methods.
Something like this

```
"Access-Control-Request-Methods": "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST"
```

Check this question [Default value for Access-Control-Request-Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478312/default-value-for-access-control-request-methods)

Comment: I am getting like this when  making a post request ...  `Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`